# Automatically insert first character of previous line

Tags: vimrc, vimscript

In a fortran code, I have lines like

```
c    write(6,*) "something"
     write(6,*) "something_else"
```

I would like to insert the first character of the previous line when I open a new line with <kbd>o</kbd> in normal mode or <kbd>enter</kbd> in insert mode.
In the example given, if I open a new line under the `1st` line, the line should open with a `c` and when I open new line under the `2nd`, the new line should start with a whitespace. How would I do that in vim?

P.S. Kindly add appropriate tags if you find any. I could only find `vimscript` and `vimrc` which might even be not so appropriate.

Comment: something like this perhaps: `nnoremap o o<c-y>`

Comment: Also, it might be worth saying that in this context, `c` is the character for commenting.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt That doesn't work for lines beginning with whitespace since it also prints the first non-whitespace character along with the whitespace

Comment: @KritixiLithos That's why it is only a comment and no real solution. However I think this one does really what the OP wants: `nnoremap o o<c-u><c-y>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible approach is to use custom function:

```
function! MyFunction()
  let curline = getline(line('.'))
  let char = " "
  if len(curline)
    let char = curline[0]
  endif
  let l:r = append(line('.'), char)
  let l:r = setpos('.', [0, line('.')+1, 3, 1])
endfunction

nnoremap o :call MyFunction()<CR>A
inoremap <CR> <Esc>:call MyFunction()<CR>A
```

Using above mapping will make it work both in normal and insert mode.

Comment: Works perfectly! Mecri!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your vimrc:

```vim
nnoremap o 0ylo^OP
```

where `^O` is the character literal for `<C-o>`

The first thing that happens in the mapping is that you go to the beginning of the line `0` and yank the first character `yl`. Then you go ahead and create a newline below the current line `o`. All that's left now is to paste that character, so we execute `<C-o>` (which allows us to execute one normal mode command while in insert mode) and we paste that register to the left of our cursor `P`.

Comment: When I do 'o', A new line starts with the character ^OP.

Comment: @Sathyam You have to type `<C-v><C-o>` in insert mode to print the literal `^O`